# Rigging - Is it normal for limbs to rotate when you set their pole targets?

Tags: animation, rigging

My character with his arms spread directly out to the side with the top of his hands facing upwards.

The moment I set the pole target for his arms, the arms rotate in such a way that the palms of his hands are facing their pole targets, instead of upwards.  This is causing some annoying twisting of the mesh.

I can fix the twisting by rotating the arm bone's pole angle, but that throws off the direction of the joints towards their pole targets.  i.e. causing knee to bend off to the side of the body instead of out in front of it.

Is this normal for the arms and legs to rotate towards their pole targets?