# Rigging - How do I change pole angle without affecting the mesh?

Tags: rigging

The title says it all. When I change the pole angle of a bone to match the bones that control the direction knees and elbows are facing the mesh gets all twisted. How do I avoid this?

I'm using this rigging method:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU

EDIT: As you see the elbow is bending up, but I want it to bend back without the arm getting rotated (because of how the arm is shaped)
[image]

Comment: Propably the vertex group for this bone is all over the body, try to find the vertex group delete it and weight paint the parts of the mesh for that bone your self

Comment: @IgorTatarnikov The weight painting is fine. I added a picture and some additional details of the problem which should make understanding the issue a little bit easier.

Comment: It would be easier if you will add your blend file

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [Rigging - Is it normal for limbs to rotate when you set their pole targets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/rigging-is-it-normal-for-limbs-to-rotate-when-you-set-their-pole-targets?) ...unfortunately there's no answer there either.